# Login to gmail using HtmlUnit

Tags: java, servlets, htmlunit

I am trying automate login to gmail but its not working. I am using HtmlUnit for form,textbox and submit button access. On passing correct username and password it displays all the services but in the end when i open gmail it shows the login page.

This is my code

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    // Get the first page
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);

    try {
        final HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.gmail.com/");
        final HtmlForm form = page1.getForms().get(0);
        final HtmlSubmitInput button = form.getInputByName("signIn");
        final HtmlTextInput textField = form.getInputByName("Email");
        final HtmlPasswordInput pwd = form.getInputByName("Passwd");
        textField.setValueAttribute("username");
        pwd.setValueAttribute("password");
        System.out.println(page1.asText());
        final HtmlPage page2 = (HtmlPage) button.click();

        String htmlBody = page2.getWebResponse().getContentAsString();
        System.out.println(page2.asText());
        System.out.println("Base Uri 1 : " + page1);
        System.out.println("Base Uri 2 : " + page2);

        webClient.closeAllWindows();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

This is Error Log i am getting

```
    Oct 17, 2014 8:51:09 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.InputElementFactory createElementNS
INFO: Bad input type: "email", creating a text input
Gmail
One account. All of Google.
Sign in to continue to Gmail
Email username Password password Sign in checked Stay signed in
For your convenience, keep this checked. On shared devices, additional precautions are recommended. Learn more
Need help?
Create an account
One Google Account for everything Google
About Google
Privacy & Terms
Help
?English (United States)?
Oct 17, 2014 8:51:20 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl runSingleJob
SEVERE: Job run failed with unexpected RuntimeException: CustomError: Error in protected function: Cannot call method "Xi" of null (script in https://mail.google.com/_/scs/mail-static/_/js/k=gmail.main.en.abFelT_TrjE.O/m=m_i,t,it/am=HCOG-3_3B5Ez3KUPqv3733OfFD97D_7vTQAk7ASA_83-H0Dvgf1Qfmg/rt=h/d=1/t=zcms/rs=AItRSTMh1uD80u0Q-oPCPkAWIHZAIOe3nQ from (57, 18) to (114, 10)#67)
======= EXCEPTION START ========
Exception class=[net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.JavaScriptException]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: CustomError: Error in protected function: Cannot call method "Xi" of null (script in https://mail.google.com/_/scs/mail-static/_/js/k=gmail.main.en.abFelT_TrjE.O/m=m_i,t,it/am=HCOG-3_3B5Ez3KUPqv3733OfFD97D_7vTQAk7ASA_83-H0Dvgf1Qfmg/rt=h/d=1/t=zcms/rs=AItRSTMh1uD80u0Q-oPCPkAWIHZAIOe3nQ from (57, 18) to (114, 10)#67)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:705)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:620)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:513)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:637)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.callFunction(JavaScriptEngine.java:612)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeJavaScriptFunctionIfPossible(HtmlPage.java:1001)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptFunctionJob.runJavaScript(JavaScriptFunctionJob.java:53)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptExecutionJob.run(JavaScriptExecutionJob.java:102)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.runSingleJob(JavaScriptJobManagerImpl.java:328)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.background.DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.run(DefaultJavaScriptExecutor.java:162)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.JavaScriptException: [object Object] (script in https://mail.google.com/_/scs/mail-static/_/js/k=gmail.main.en.abFelT_TrjE.O/m=m_i,t,it/am=HCOG-3_3B5Ez3KUPqv3733OfFD97D_7vTQAk7ASA_83-H0Dvgf1Qfmg/rt=h/d=1/t=zcms/rs=AItRSTMh1uD80u0Q-oPCPkAWIHZAIOe3nQ from (57, 18) to (114, 10)#67)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1006)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:798)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:411)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:309)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3057)
    at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:103)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$4.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:630)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:690)
    ... 10 more
JavaScriptException value = [object Object]
== CALLING JAVASCRIPT ==

  function () {
      if (b.isDisposed()) {
          return a.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      try {
          return a.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      catch (c) {
          b.xa(c);
          if (!b.Ba) {
              throw b.Aa && ("object" === typeof c ? c.message = "Error in protected function: " + c.message : c = "Error in protected function: " + c), c;
          }
          throw new Yba(c);
      }
      finally {
      }
  }

======= EXCEPTION END ========

Oct 17, 2014 8:51:21 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 17, 2014 8:51:21 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 17, 2014 8:51:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 17, 2014 8:51:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 17, 2014 8:51:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 17, 2014 8:51:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Oct 17, 2014 8:51:22 PM com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.IncorrectnessListenerImpl notify
WARNING: Obsolete content type encountered: 'text/javascript'.
Gmail
Basic HTML view
<style> #loading {display:none} </style><form action="?ui=html&amp;zy=c" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="at" value="AF6bupN_lVxTXggheNEbct_StIuAzk-YxQ"><font face=arial>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Gmail in standard view. However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. To use standard view, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, then <a href="">try again</a>.<p>To use Gmail's basic HTML view, which does not require JavaScript, <input type="submit" value="click here" class="submit_as_link">.</p></font></form><form action="?ui=mobile&amp;zyp=c" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="at" value="AF6bupN_lVxTXggheNEbct_StIuAzk-YxQ"><p><font face=arial>If you want to view Gmail on a mobile phone or similar device <input type="submit" value="click here" class="submit_as_link">.</font></p></form>
Loading harishmohanani28@gmail.com…
Loading standard view | Load basic HTML (for slow connections)
This is taking longer than usual. Try reloading the page.
If that doesn't work, you can:
1. Disable Labs and try again.
2. If you're on a slow connection, try basic HTML view.
3. For more troubleshooting tips, visit the help center.

Skip to content
Using Gmail with screen readers
Keyboard shortcuts
Gmail (standard view) guide
This version of Chrome is no longer supported. Please upgrade to asupported browser. Dismiss
+Harish
+Harish
Search
YouTube
Maps
Play
News
Gmail
Drive
Calendar
Gmail
Add a shortcut
More
Translate
Books
Blogger
Photos
My Business
Even more from Google
Share
Change photo
Harish Mohanani
harishmohanani28@gmail.com
Account–Privacy
View profile
Harish Mohanani
harishmohanani28@gmail.com (default)
All your Google+ pages ›
Add account
Sign out
Search
Hidden fields
Gmail Logo





>
<
Conversations





Primary

Social

Promotions

>
<
English
English Dvorak
??????
???????? (???????)
?????? (INSCRIPT)
Enable personal dictionary
Hide Keyboard
Input Tools Settings
Base Uri 1 : HtmlPage(https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1)@26946257
Base Uri 2 : HtmlPage(https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/)@16175221
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that the built-in browser can't parse the Javascript correctly.

Try emulating a different browser. From [the docs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html):

> Often you will want to simulate a specific browser. This is done by passing a com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion into the WebClient constructor. Constants have been provided for some common browsers but you can create your own specific version by instantiating a BrowserVersion.

```
@Test
public void homePage_Firefox() throws Exception {
    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_17);
    final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
    Assert.assertEquals("HtmlUnit - Welcome to HtmlUnit", page.getTitleText());

    webClient.closeAllWindows();
}
```

This snippet emulates Firefox v17. You can see the full list of supported, emulatable browsers [in these javadocs](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/BrowserVersion.html). Today, these are:

```
static BrowserVersion   CHROME
static BrowserVersion   FIREFOX_17
static BrowserVersion   FIREFOX_24
static BrowserVersion   INTERNET_EXPLORER_11
static BrowserVersion   INTERNET_EXPLORER_8
static BrowserVersion   INTERNET_EXPLORER_9
```

Comment: thanks for your response. It worked. There are no exception now but still I am getting gmail log in page. Is it a problem with cookies? If so how do I solve it?

Comment: Maybe. If you re-create `webClient` every single request, you're essentially throwing away the cookies. It could be that.

Comment: That's up to you how you want to design it. At the least, encapsulate all your code in a method, make the client a parameter, and pass it in to multiple requests. Or you can make it singleton, or static, or something else.

Comment: Thank you @ashes999 for ur answer. I want to design a website that saves username and password for sites like google, facebook etc and let's you to login automatically but I don't know where to start from. What would I have to learn first?

Comment: I would suggest using existing sites instead of rolling your own. Saving passwords and user names is a very security-sensitive issue. Please mark this as the correct answer (white checkmark next to the up/down buttons) if I answered your original question.