# Disable Captcha (Login Challenge) For Google Login

Tags: gmail, captcha, google-workspace

I try to login to my google account with using HtmlUnit like [Login to gmail using HtmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26428699/login-to-gmail-using-htmlunit)

But I encounter with Captcha on password step. I tried to disable it with https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha but it didn't work. Any idea?

Note: By the way it is a g-suite account and I'm sure that code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used **selenium headless** instead of htmlunit and solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

A captcha is what would be called a "login challenge". Since it is a Google Workspace (G Suite) account, I would recommend you [to turn it OFF](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2537800?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctemporarily-turn-off-a-login-challenge) for 10 minutes in case you are an admin, otherwise, if you do not have the access to do it yourself, you can ask your admin.

Login challenges can not be turned OFF in Google accounts unless you set up 2 factor authentication.

Comment: thanks four your answer. I have another account and it works like that I want. So I don't think so this is an only option.

Comment: Have you also tried by enabling the option in your account to allow access to "Less secure apps"? https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: yes tried but not worked.

Comment: I think you may need to contact support at this point, or maybe try by turning the login challenge OFF for 10 minutes. Also make sure that the app is whitelisted in the API controls of the Google Workspace Admin Console. Remember that Google Workspace account are business accounts and have extra security, so if the other account that works fine is a consumer account it would be expected for it to work fine, but not the business one.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

```
pip install undetected-chromedriver
```

Step 2
[enter link description here](https://github.com/robert456456456456/selenium-python-captcha/blob/main/test.py)